# MFCでCFileDialogを拡張したい

Tags: c++, mfc

お世話になっております。

MFCでは
CFileDialog
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dk77e5e7.aspx
でWindowsの一般的なファイルを開いたりするダイアログを作成できます。

その画面をWindowsタブ等で利用する際に、タッチしやすいようにダイアログそのものの見た目の全体サイズを拡大し、「開く」「キャンセル」等のボタンを大きく表示させたいと考えています。

具体的なコードがわかりませんので教えていただければ幸いです。
環境はwin7 VS2008SP1となります。

Answer (score 1):

> ダイアログそのものの見た目の全体サイズを拡大し、「開く」「キャンセル」等のボタンを大きく表示させたいと考えています。

おそらく、[`CFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dk77e5e7.aspx) では実現不可能かと思います。このAPIで表示されるダイアログは[Windows OS標準提供のダイアログ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/5fcd0hw9.aspx)のため、きめ細かいカスタマイズは出来ないと思います。

ダイアログ上にラジオボタンやラベル等を追加する程度であれば、同クラスの [`SetTemplate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/h6fdxy1c.aspx) や [`GetIFileDialogCustomize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb398757.aspx) を利用できます。ただし、あくまでUI部品の"追加"となるため、既存ダイアログ部分には干渉できません。